# How does the mechanical linkage of the airspeed indicator convert dynamic pressure to KIAS?

Tags: flight-instruments, airspeed, pitot-static

I understand the underlying principle of an airspeed indicator, ie. that it uses the Pitot-static system to measure the dynamic pressure as the difference between total pressure and static pressure.

Knowing that the dynamic pressure is $p_{d} = \frac{1}{2}\rho u^2,$ any linear variation in the measure will be a linear variation in $u^2$, not in $u$ alone. Yet the airspeed indicator markings are themselves uniformly spaced and still, they show $u$, not $u^2$. Therefore: how does the mechanical linkage convert a linear displacement (variation) in the dynamic pressure measurement $\propto u^2$ into $u$?

That is, how is the square root transformation of the dynamic pressure performed at the *clockwork level* of the airspeed indicator to obtain the indicated air speed?

My guess is that one of the gearwheels will be responsible for this but I haven't actually been able to find any information on this online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]
([YouTube](https://youtu.be/HM7ZMPpbeDA))

As the diaphragm inflates, it pushes a levered arm up, which drives a gear via a **hollowed curved track** (not via the cogs). The bigger the inflation, the smaller the rotation of the gear ([arm increasing radius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUBnz.png)) compared to the piston displacement. It's the only variable in the mechanism that is not a fixed ratio.

Full disclosure: this is my analysis of the video, I haven't designed one before.

Comment: Do you reckon, in this example, that it is the shape of the hollowed track that does the square root transformation of the displacement then?

Comment: @沖原ハーベスト - I do, it's the only variable in the mechanism that is not a fixed ratio.

Comment: Ah. clever, indeed. Still, looks like a very fragile piece of machinery. I'd need to open an ASI one day. Thanks for the pointer to the video.

Answer (score 1):

Some early airspeed indicators were much simpler.

[image]
[image]
[image]