# How does an airspeed indicator look from the inside?

Tags: flight-instruments, airspeed

How does a typical GA airspeed indicator look from the inside and how does it work?

Comment: @JohnK please provide an answer instead of a snarky comment

Answer (score 6):

The *Indicated Airspeed (IAS)* is measured based on the difference between the *static air pressure* (measured via the static port) and the *ram air pressure* (measured via the pitot tube). A typical GA airspeed indicator looks like this:

[image: Airspeed Indicator]
(source: [Wikimedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/ASI-operation-FAA.png))

The difference in the pressures causes the diaphragm to flex. This flexing is then mechanically translated into a rotation of the indicator. See this question for the full details: [How does the mechanical linkage of the airspeed indicator convert dynamic pressure to KIAS?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/50048/how-does-the-mechanical-linkage-of-the-airspeed-indicator-convert-dynamic-pressu?rq=1)

Comment: Hi, thanks for for your explanation, I know how it works - just interested to know how it looks from the inside . What the hell I’ve just noticed my question changed, I didn’t mention “how does it work.” Like I wrote above I’m just interested to know how the instrument look from inside ...

Comment: @Mikenosmith Yes, I edited your question because there were votes to close it. Feel free to edit it again if this is not what you wanted to know.

Comment: And why is that ?

Comment: @Mikenosmith Why is what? You have to be more clear about what you want to know. Your original question had votes to close it because of "Unclear what you are asking".